# Is there any other way to add an external js script in vue js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am adding an external js script in vue js component like this :

```
mounted() {
                let spotlighterScript = document.createElement('script')
                spotlighterScript.setAttribute('src', 'www.domain.com/assets/demo.js')
                spotlighterScript.setAttribute('Content-Type', 'text/javascript')
                document.head.appendChild(spotlighterScript)
            },
```

Is there any other way to add an external js script in vue js component inside compute or any other way?

Comment: There are bunch of extensions for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-load-script one of them =)

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 Using a plugin

First install vue-plugin-load-script via npm or yarn

```
npm install --save vue-plugin-load-script
```

In main.js add

```
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);

Vue.loadScript(scriptUrl)
 .then(() => {
   // Script is loaded, do something
 })
 .catch(() => {
   // Failed to fetch script
 });
```

Thank you [@halilcakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020919/halilcakar) for mentioning this method. I didn't know about this plugin until you showed it off.

## Method 2 Implementing manually

```js
mounted() {
    //script already loaded exit
    if (document.getElementById('external-source-script')) return;

    //Create script tag
    let script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute('src', 'your-external-source') // <---------------
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
    script.setAttribute('id', 'external-source-script')
 
    //Add external script dependency 
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}


beforeDestroy() {
    //Remove the external source
    let el = document.getElementById('external-source-script')
    if (el) el.remove();
}
```